# cómo funciona after en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo este código de python para crear un evento que se ejecuta cada segundo. Y sí funciona, el problema es que no entiendo bien por qué.

Según yo, en le línea de `root.after(1000,timeChanged)` está generando una llamada recursiva, pero no hay falla el límite de la recursividad.

La cosa cambia cuando se le agregan paréntesis al final `root.after(1000,timeChanged())`. Aquí sí manda error de recursividad.

¿Saben por qué es distinto y por qué es que funciona?

```html
import tkinter as tk
import time

def timeChanged():
    date = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    timeLabel.configure(text = date)
    root.after(1000,timeChanged)
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Ventana")
root.geometry("400x400")

#timeLabel = tk.Label(root, bg = "orange", textvariable = var, padx = 5, pady = 5, width = 10)
timeLabel = tk.Label(root, bg = "orange", text = "h", padx = 5, pady = 5, width = 10)
timeLabel.pack()

timeChanged()

root.mainloop()
```

``

Answer (score 3):

Axel, cuando ejecutas tú código, el intérprete de python lee todo el contenido del archivo, y ejecuta cada instrucción que puede. Para que una función pueda ser llamada, es necesario que agregues los paréntesis al final del nombre de ésta, como es el caso de la penúltima línea del código que muestras.

```
timeChanged()  # Aquí se está llamando a la función timeChanged
```

En cambio, cuando usas **after**, no estás ejecutando la función directamente, sino que le estás diciendo a after que la lance luego de x milisegundos, entonces, cuando el intérprete lee lo siguiente:

```
def timeChanged():
    date = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    timeLabel.configure(text = date)
    root.after(1000,timeChanged)
```

Sólo está leyendo la definición de la función, pero no la está ejecutando.

Sin embargo, cuando haces la llamada incluyendo los paréntesis, le estás diciendo al intérprete que ejecute esa invocación en ese mismo momento:

```
root.after(1000,timeChanged())
```

Por lo que el código no se sigue leyendo y comienza a iterar recursivamente, hasta que se produzca el error.

Answer (score 2):

La razón por la que la llamada no es recursiva, es que la función `timeChanged` **retorna** antes de ser llamada otra vez.

Es decir, en pseudocódigo sería algo como:

```
def timeChanged():
    mostrar la hora
    pedir al planificador que ejecute timeChanged dentro de 1 segundo
    RETORNAR
```

la función retorna, en vez de llamarse a sí misma. Cuando el scheduler la llame otra vez dentro de 1 segundo, también retornará inmediatamente. No se anidan las llamadas.

Otra cosa sería:

```
def timeChanged():
    mostrar la hora
    esperar 1 segundo
    timeChanged()
    RETORNAR   (nunca se alcanza)
```

pues en este caso la función nunca retornaría ya que al final, se llama a sí misma. (Esto, además de agotar los niveles de recursión, también bloquea el bucle de eventos, al no retornar nunca).