# Activar cámara PC para guardar VideoCapture con GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, video

Quiero en una ventana colocar dos botones.

Botón 1 --> Iniciar grabación, permitirá activar la cámara del pc y guardar un archivo de vídeo.
Botón 2 --> Detener grabación, finalizara la grabación de la cámara.

**Al intentarlo, la ventana raíz se congela**, para finalizar debo presionar la letra destinada para tal fin que se ha programado.

Código :

```
import tkinter
import cv2
from tkinter import *

def save_video():

    global out
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') 
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0,(640, 480)) 
    
    while (True): 
        ret, frame = cap.read()  
        if ret ==True: 
            x = cv2.imshow('x',frame)
            y = out.write(frame)  
            
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
                break
        else: break
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def end_record():

    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


root = tkinter.Tk()

root.title('Guardar video')

root.geometry('500x300')

root.resizable(0,0)

Button(root,text='* Guardar',   fg="blue", command =save_video, widt=20, relief="groove", font=("arial",13)).place(x=5, y=10)

Button(root,text='* Finalizar', fg="blue", command =end_record, widt=20, relief="groove", font=("arial",13)).place(x=5, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tu problema es que estas ejecutando dos bucles infinitos `root.mainloop()` y `while True : `, cuando haces esto tu aplicación de tkinter deja de funcionar. Puedes utiliza la función `.after()` para evitar este problema. Este link te será de utilidad https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245082/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-after-en-tkinter?rq=1